# Поиск шрифта

Tags: шрифты

Посоветуйте, плиз, бесплатные веб-шрифты, с поддержкой кириллицы, похожие на Officina Sans Bold Cyrillic и Officina Sans Book Cyrillic.
У меня получилось найти [Cuprum](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cuprum) и [Scada](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Scada)
интересует, может есть еще что-то?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.searchfreefonts.com/categories/cyrillic.htm

http://www.free-fonts.com/font/cyrillic.html